# Swift 5 - Cannot INSERT data into SQLite table after performing SELECT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, swift5

I am experiencing an issue during iOS app development.

Xcode Version: 11
Swift Version: 5

There are two views for the app - First_View and Second_View.
On the First_View, there is a collection view which is to list out the data in table "custom_location" from SQLite. There is a button on First_View which button is to navigate to Second_View.

On Second_View, there is a collection view which is to list out data in table "all_location" from SQLite. User can select the item and that item will be inserted into table "custom_location".

The behavior of current issue:
If there is any record in table "custom_location", the First_View will display those data when the app is launched. Then I try to click the button to navigate the Second_View and select an item. However, that item cannot be inserted into "custom_location".

I notice if the "custom_location" in the beginning, the Second_View is able to insert data into "custom_location".

Related code for selecting and inserting from SQLite:

```
public static func getCustomLocationList() -> [Int] {
    var customLocationList:[Int] = []
    var locationId:Int = -1
    var db :SQLiteConnect?
    //Database connection path
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let sqlitePath = urls[urls.count-1].absoluteString + Settings.dbName
    db = SQLiteConnect(path: sqlitePath)

    if let mydb = db{
        let statement = mydb.fetch("custom_location_list", cond: "location_id > 0", order: "id DESC")
        while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW{
            locationId = Int(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1))

            customLocationList.append(locationId)
        }
    }

    return customLocationList
}


public static func insertCustomLocation(_ locationId: Int){
    var db :SQLiteConnect?
    //Database connection path
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let sqlitePath = urls[urls.count-1].absoluteString + Settings.dbName
    db = SQLiteConnect(path: sqlitePath)

    if let mydb = db {
        mydb.insert("custom_location_list", rowInfo: ["location_id":"\(locationId)"])
    }
}
```

In my SQLiteConnect.swift, the function "fetch" and "insert" is:

```
func fetch(_ tableName :String, cond :String?, order :String?) -> OpaquePointer {
    var statement :OpaquePointer? = nil
    var sql = "select * from \(tableName)"
    if let condition = cond {
        sql += " where \(condition)"
    }

    if let orderBy = order {
        sql += " order by \(orderBy)"
    }

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, sql.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), -1, &statement, nil)
    return statement!
}

func insert(_ tableName :String, rowInfo :[String:String]) -> Bool {
    var statement :OpaquePointer? = nil
    let sql = "insert into \(tableName) " + "(\(rowInfo.keys.joined(separator: ","))) " + "values (\(rowInfo.values.joined(separator: ",")))"
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, sql.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            return true
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code or used print to check what sql statement is used to insert? You have no error handling for your sql code, why? Wouldn’t it help? Do you have a primary key defined for the table you are inserting into?

Comment: I tried to print the sql code which is "insert into custom_location_list (location_id) values (10)". This sql can be executed on my SQLite DB browser.

Comment: I tried to comment out the getCustomLocationList on the First_View, this issue can be fixed... But the First_View is required to use "getCustomLocationList" to display the custom location list.......

Comment: I also tried to debug on Xcode, i notice "sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE" is equal false if First_View called "getCutomLocationList" to get a non-empty list.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed.

The root cause is the DB connect is opened on other method and I set "return" in the middle of that function... Then the DB connection has not been terminated when the function is completed.